# How to get props from <Route /> with react router dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass `:id` to url when i click a row of my table
trying using `navigate("/edit/"+props);` and `onClick={() => handleClick(data.PacienteId)}` but it didnt work then used `useParams` and created `handleProceed` to use it as `onclick={handleProceed}` but it still not working i just get url provided by `Apiurl` but `/undefined`

This is what i have in my routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Login  />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact element={<Dashboard  />} />
          <Route path="/new" exact element={<Nuevo  />} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" exact element={<Editar />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my dashboard where i want to pass id to url clicking on table

```
export const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const [paciente, setPaciente] = useState([]);
  const {id}=useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = `${Apiurl}pacientes?page=1`;
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setPaciente(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (props) => {
    /* navigate("/edit/" + props); */
    navigate(`/edit/${id}`);
  };
  const handleProceed = (e) => {
    /* history.push(`/edit/${id}`); */
    navigate(`/edit/${id}`);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">DNI</th>
              <th scope="col">NOMBRE</th>
              <th scope="col">TELEFONO</th>
              <th scope="col">CORREO</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {paciente.map((data, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i} /* onClick={handleProceed} */onClick={() => handleClick(data.PacienteId)}>
                  <td>{data.PacienteId}</td>
                  <td>{data.DNI}</td>
                  <td>{data.Nombre}</td>
                  <td>{data.Telefono}</td>
                  <td>{data.Correo}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Since the route path mentioned with `<Dashboard/>` contains no parameters, it returns undefined. The issue is that you are navigating to the path `/edit/{id}` but you are accessing the route param in `<Dashboard/>` component. In your code, you can access the route param id inside the component `<Editar/>` that is declared with the `/edit/{id}` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handle click function you have the parameter named as props, but you've tried to use "id" variable in the navigate method. Either use props in the navigate method or change the argument  name to id.

```
 const handleClick = (id) => {
   navigate(`/edit/${id}`);
 };
```

********* OR ************

```
 const handleClick = (props) => {
   navigate(`/edit/${props}`);
 };
```

Comment: After redirecting to `edit/idclicked` i want to reuse this id to make another url to call API. i used `useEffect(()=>{
let id = props.match.params.id` but an error says props.match is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Use `const {id} = useParams();`

then

> ``` const handleProceed = (id) => { /* history.push(``/edit/${id}``); */ navigate(``/edit/${id}``); }; ```